# Fragment and activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am doing my project and i am trying to do like 1 `activity` and the others will be `fragment`. But the problem now i am facing is, the main content from `activity_main.xml` is not showing as usual after I implement the `<FrameLayout>` in my `activity_main.xml`.

But the thing is the fragment activity is showing instead of the main activity content. 
Someone can give me some example about the correct way to implement of fragment and can run both fragment and activity in the same time?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/login_background">
</FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**PS** sorry for late edit. This is my screenshot of my work.

This is before adding the `<FrameLayout>` and everything looks good:

[image: before]

This is after adding the `<FrameLayout>` and it hide the activity behind:

[image: after]

Comment: can you edit the question and include the xml?

Comment: @Aquaballin check again. whats wrong with my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/viewPage"
android:background="YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR">
...
...

</FrameLayout>
```

Place it as parent of your `coordinatorLayout`

Comment: WHAT THE FCK. thanks.. thats what I looking for so long long time. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your layout is your FrameLayout is filling up your activity layout.

You can fix it by adding root layout that determine where the position of FrameLayout according to your `contain_main`. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent>

          <include layout="@layout/content_main"
              android:id="@+id/content_main_ly"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

          <FrameLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
              android:layout_below="@+id/content_main_ly"
              android:background="@drawable/login_background">
          </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You need to make sure the position of your content_main in your `activity_main.xml` so it always above or shown. Try moving all the View inside the `CoordinatorLayout` to a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`.

Comment: move all the view(in my case) which is `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and all the stuff ? and inside a empty `RelativeLayout` like this `<RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent>` ?

Comment: Something like that. You need to test it.

Comment: Try sketching your design and add it to your question so everybody can know what the UI that you've expected.

Comment: No problem, you don't need to sorry for that ;)

Comment: i am wondering if i cant solve this problem, is it a good way for me to use activity to replace all my fragment activity instead of using the fragment.